# UITabBarController, any possible way to move next View Controller with horizontal swipe?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ios4

I am new to iOS. Not sure if there is a possiblity to bring the following logic.

```
1. UITabBarController has three UIViewController.
2. While Swipping horizontally in the second UIViewController, i want to move
   to the third UIViewController.
```

Is it possible?. if so, kindly advice how to achieve the same.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the Second ViewController add the following lines in ViewDidLoad

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeRecognizer = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(gotoNextPage:)];
[self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeRecognizer];
[swipeRecognizer release];
```

And add method

```
-(void)gotoNextPage:(id)sender {
    [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:thirdViewController];
}
```

Comment: Can you please try the following code?     for(UIViewController *viewController in self.tabBarController.viewControllers) {
        if([viewController isKindOfClass:[THIRDVIEWCONTROLLER class]]) {
            [self.tabBarController setSelectedViewController:viewController];
        }
    }

Answer (score 0):

You can use Touch Delegate Method i am doing to pop to previous view

```
-(void)touchesMoved:(NSSet *)touches withEvent:(UIEvent *)event
{
    UITouch *touch = [touches anyObject];

    CGPoint startPosoition = [touch previousLocationInView:self.view];


    CGPoint endPosition = [touch locationInView:self.view];

    if (endPosition.x - startPosoition.x > 20)
    {
        [self.navigationController popViewControllerAnimated:YES];
    } else
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes that can be done. For 1. I assume you know how to setup a tabbar based app with viewcontrollers. For 2. Implement the swipe gesture recognizer on your second view controller's view and in the gesture handler do: `[self.yourTabBarController setSelectedIndex:2];`

Answer (score 0):

Use this code;

```
UISwipeGestureRecognizer *swipeGestureNextPage = [[UISwipeGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(loadPreviousPageClicked)];
 swipeGestureNextPage.direction = UISwipeGestureRecognizerDirectionRight;
 [self.view addGestureRecognizer:swipeGestureNextPage];

-(void)loadPreviousPageClicked
{

//use navigation controller here accordingly

}
```

Thats it.